# What is the recomended way / best practice to Poedit translate strings without a source keyword?

Tags: zend-framework2, translation, translate, poedit

I'm developing a Zend Framework 2 application an having a problem with translations. Actually in the view scripts a can use the view helper [`Translate`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/I18n/View/Helper/Translate.php). Since I defined "translate" as a source keyword in Poedit (`[Poedit menu] -> Catalogue -> Properties... -> Source keywords`) the strings are identified by the tool and added to the tranlation list.

But there are also some strings at other places, where I cannot use the/a view helper, e.g. in form classes or in the navigation. How should this be managed?

Some ideas:

1. Create a file with a list of such strings. Example: We create files `navigation.i18n`, `forms.i18n` etc. (or just one file), define there all strings we need in the common Poedit syntax we added to the `Source keywords` list (e.g. with `translate`: `translate('my label foo'), translate('my label bar')` etc.), and finally add `i18n` as a source path (`[Poedit menu] -> Catalogue -> Properties... -> Source paths`). We also can use an extension, that is already defined as a 'Source paths'.
2. A class, that provides one (static) method `translate(...)` without any functionality. Example: Instead of `'label' => 'foo'`we use `'label' => \MyNamespace\Util\Translator::translate('foo')`

I think, the second appoach is cleaner, and I like more. I don't need to write my key sring twice and to hold in the head, what is already translated / updated. But maybe there are better ideas?

Comment: U can access the translator pretty much everywhere ;) Simply inject the translator or the ServiceManager / ServiceLocator itself ;)

Comment: @Sam Oh, it would be great! How can I access it then in an model/table class? E.g. wenn an `Expression` is used: `$select->columns(array('title' => new Expression('IFNULL(sports.title, "' . 'unassigned')));`

Comment: I can translate the string in the view scrtip, e.g.: `$this->translate($sport->title)`. But it will only be possible, if the key string has already been added to the `.po` file. That means, I need access to the Service Locator from my table class. Well, I can pass it as constructor argument, when I'm creating its object in the `Module` class, and use is directly in the Table class. But then I need every time to take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

Just add keyword `_` to Poedit (`[Poedit menu] -> Catalogue -> Properties... -> Source keywords`). Then instead of a label use function `_` with this label.
For example change

```
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Username',
        ),
```

to

```
        'options' => array(
            'label' => _('Username'),
        ),
```

and in Poedit update Catalog From Sources. That's it -- now you have your label in Poedit.

Answer (score 0):

I still do not really understand where your problem lies :S From everything i can tell, you're trying to translate the output of a Model/Entity. This is a typical concern of the View!

If the main concern is "How to get all those Model-Output into PoEdit?", then all i can tell you is: either manually or to implement DB-Translation...

Injecting the ServiceManager into basically everything following this syntax of `getServiceConfig()`

```
return array( 'factories' => array(
    'my-service' => function ($sm) {
        $class = new ServiceClass();
        $class->setServiceManager($sm);
        return $class;
    }
));
```

In the above example `$class` can pretty much be everything. A Model/Entity, a TableGateway or whatever you desire.

Comment: Where the problem lies: First of all I have to use the `translate()` (or another registered Poedit `keyword`) somewhere in the code, in order to pass strings to Poedit automatically. Right? Now. Where can I do that? The label value gets defined in the `Form` class. That means, I cannot use the `Translate` view helper (= Poedit keyword) for it in the view. But I also cannot use it in the Form class. (OK, maybe I could theoretically somehow, but... 1. how? 2. view helper in a `Form` class?..) So I cannot understand, how to pass my labels to Poedit and translate them correctly.

Comment: Well, i suppose you could always add `'label' => '%s'` to PoEdit, that'd only require you to never have additional (CodeFormat) spaces in there? Couple of things are just better of done manually sometimes ^^

Comment: A pattern like `'label' => '%s'` does unfortunately not work, since Poedit needs a function and parses then its argument(-s). Manually? OK, maybe. Or with the second workaround I described in the question.

Comment: Yeps, the 2nd workaround is actually something that's becoming a little familiar in some open source projects where people add a language-strings file additionally.

Comment: What's you telling about is the first workaround. Anyway, do you have an example of a project, where this approach is being used?

Answer (score 0):

If you build your form in a different way, like so:

```
$name = new \Zend\Form\Element('name');
$name->setLabel('Your name');
$name->setAttributes(array(
    'type'  => 'text'
));
$this->add($name);
```

( http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html )

Then you can register "setLabel" as keyword in poedit, and it will pick up the label-text for translation.