# ZF2 navigation translate navigation labels and titles

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-translate

I'm trying to find a way to translate the labels and titles.
According to he [ZF2 Manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.navigation.view.helpers.html) all I have to do this:

> The navigation helpers support translation of page labels and titles. You can set a translator of type Zend\I18n\Translator in the helper using $helper->setTranslator($translator).

So my navigation looks like this in config file

```
return array(
    'navigation' => array(
        'default' => array(
            array(
                'label' => 'Home',
                'route' => 'home',
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'Users',
                'route' => 'tar-users',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

This is in global.php

```
return array(
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'navigation' => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory',
        ),
    ),

    //...
);
```

And in my layout I have:

```
<?php echo $this->navigation('navigation')
        ->setTranslator($this->plugin('translate')->getTranslator())
        ->menu()
        ->setUlClass('nav navbar-nav')
        ->setMaxDepth(0)
    ?>
```

The navigation is working but is not translating. 
I'm sure I missed something or I did something wrong. I'd like to know what. I don't what you to write the code just some tips.

Thank you.

Comment: I found something that is solving my problem for now until I find a more elegant way to do it. Take a look at the @Remi Tomas answer. [How to translate form labels in Zend Framework 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961628/how-to-translate-form-labels-in-zend-framework-2)

Comment: Do You have translations for words "Home" and "Users" in translation file ?

Comment: poedit didn't recognize the navigation labels

Answer (score 1):

Zend uses `.po` files in `Application/language` folder, and you need to use [poedit](http://poedit.net/) to edit gettext translations. Poedit scans the .`php` ( or `.phtml` files in this case ) for phrases to translate, more precisely, seeks for the translate function name ( `translate` in this case ). Check [HERE](http://samminds.com/2012/09/create-po-language-files-using-poedit/) how to configure poedit for Zend, and [HERE](https://coderwall.com/p/atvtbw/how-to-translate-zend-framework-2-config-arrays) is simple solution for translating menu labels. I have just started learning Zend, i'm not sure if this is the right approach, but it is the simplest solution that I encountered. You just need to add label values as `$translator->translate( ... )` in `Application/config/module.config.php`, an configure translator ( in skeleton application, `en_US` locale, and `gettext` type ). After that open `.po` file and refresh catalog, new lines should be added for translation ( also, you can't, and should not add new translations that are not found automatically by the program ). I have tested the above, and menu is translated automatically without `setTranslator( ... )` call.

Comment: I only had problems translating the navigation labels only. Validation messages etc are translated.

Comment: Validation messages are translated in zendframework\resources\languages, it is just php array of translations.

Comment: All I put in $translator->translate('My word') get **translated** navigation  labels no.

Answer (score 0):

do you setup the translator service and locale in your module.config.php?
something like this:

```
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'it_IT',
    'translation_files' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'phpArray',
            'filename' => __DIR__ . '/../language/Zend_Captcha.php',
            'text_domain' => 'default'
        ),
        array(
            'type'     => 'phpArray',
            'filename' => __DIR__ . '/../language/Zend_Validate.php',
            'text_domain' => 'default'
        ),
    ),
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: I'm using skeleton application, the translation is setup by default in module.config.php.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a puzzling circumstance where I had also set everything up correctly, but the translation wouldn't execute...because the proper locale wasn't installed on the OS.  I was trying to translate en_US into fr_CA.  This quickly fixed things for me:

`sudo locale-gen fr_CA
sudo locale-gen fr_CA.UTF-8`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and here is my solution. (Using `gettext`)

Example:

`module.config.php`

```
array (
    'label' => _('Home'),
    'route' => 'home'
),
```

In the View, you will use something like this:

```
$this->translate(HERE_COMES_THE_ITENS_OF_NAVIGATION)
```

In my case I use this:

```
foreach ( $this->container as $page ) {
   $this->translate($page->getlabel ());
}
```

In the POEDIT program, you will insert two sources keywords

```
1 - translate
2 - _
```

The "_" is to map the keyword by POEDIT, and ZEND uses the "translate" to replace it by the value you put inside the POEDIT.

Answer (score 0):

Zend comes with translation on navigation but not before rendering.
This snippet will do the trick. (Zend 3)

```
$sm = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
$vhm = $sm->get('ViewHelperManager');
$translator = $sm->get('translator');
$vhm->get('navigation')->setTranslator($translator);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Review the script in your module.config.php**

```
// module.config.php
fufunction _(string $msg){return $msg}

function _(string $msg){return $msg}

return array(
    'navigation' => array(
        'default' => array(
            array(
                'label' => _('Home'),
                'route' => 'home',
            ),
            array(
                'label' => _('Users'),
                'route' => 'tar-users',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'view_helpers' => [
        'aliases' => [
            '_'                 => Translate::class,
            'numberFormat'      => NumberFormat::class,
            'formLabel'         => FormLabel::class,
            'formSubmit'        => FormSubmit::class,
            'menu'              => Navigation::class,
        ],

        'factories' => [

            Translate::class => function($container) {
                $instance = new Translate();
                $instance->setTranslator($container->get(Translator::class));
                return $instance;
            },

            FormLabel::class => function($container) {
                $instance = new FormLabel();
                $instance->setTranslator($container->get(Translator::class));
                return $instance;
            },

            FormSubmit::class => function($container) {
                $instance = new FormSubmit();
                $instance->setTranslator($container->get(Translator::class));
                return $instance;
            },

            Navigation::class => function($container) {
                $instance = new Navigation();
                $instance->setTranslator($container->get(Translator::class));
                $instance->setServiceLocator($container);
                return $instance;
            },
        ]
);
```