# ZF2 Form label not translated

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, translation

Since a while I am trying to solve an issue in my forms to translate the form labels. I am using .po files to translate my strings and I have exactly done what the solution should be in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961628/how-to-translate-form-labels-in-zend-framework-2)

My translator works fine, if I test the label 'Naam' for example directly in my view as below, I get the correct translation output returned.

```
echo $this->translate('Naam'); // outputs 'Nom'
```

../module/Application/Module.php

```
$translator  = $serviceManager->get('translator');
$translator  ->setLocale($language->getLocale())
             ->setFallbackLocale('nl_NL');
             AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator);
```

../module/Application/config/module.config.php

```
'service_manager' => array(
        'aliases' => array(
            'translator' => 'MvcTranslator',
        ),
        'factories' => array(
            'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'nl_NL',
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type'     => 'gettext',
                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

ContactForm.php

```
$this->add(array(
            'name'  => 'name',
            'type'  => 'Zend\Form\Element\Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Naam',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'         => 'name',
                'autofocus'    => '',
                'autocomplete' => 'off',
                'class'        => 'form-control',
            ),
        ));
```

The view

```
<?php echo $this->form()->openTag($form); ?>
    <?php echo $this->formlabel($form->get('name')); ?> // should be 'Nom' but keeps returning 'Naam'
<?php echo $this->form()->closeTag($form); ?>
```